# Xamarin RadioButton IsChecked is reset by other RadioButtonGroup after Appearing finish

Tags: xamarin, dynamic, radio-button

I have some problem on Xamarin.Form to create dynamic RadioButton but cannot use constructor because when I create dynamic RadioButton in 3 RadioButtonGroups in OnAppearing() and set IsChecked=true of 1 RadioButton in each group but when Appearing finish all RadioButton.IsChecked from 3 groups are reset and there is only 1 button is checked. I don't konw the reason. Could anyone help me for the solution ?
Thank you.

This is my code
[C#]

```
    public class Variant {
        public string variant_name { get; set; } 
        public int show_col { get; set; } 
        public bool default_value { get; set; } 
    }


    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        GenerateChoice();
    }

    public void GenerateChoice()
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var variant in variants)
            {
                if (null == variant)
                    continue;

                GenerateRadioButton(variant);
            }
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    public void GenerateRadioButton(Variant variant)
    {
        try
        {
            RadioButton rdChoice = new RadioButton
            {
                GroupName = "Radio" + variant.show_col,
                Content = variant.variant_name,                    
                Value= variant.variant_key,
                IsEnabled = true                    
            };
            rdChoice.CheckedChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                // Perform required operation after examining e.Value
                var ctl = (RadioButton)sender;
                if (ctl.IsChecked)
                    AddVariant(variant.variant_key);
                else
                    RemoveVariant(variant.variant_key);
            };
            if (variant.default_value)
            {
                rdChoice.IsChecked = true;
            }

            // set to RadioButtonGroup
            int col = variant.show_col;
            if (0 == col)
                groupRadio1.Children.Add(rdChoice);
            else if (1 == col)
                groupRadio2.Children.Add(rdChoice);
            else if (2 == col)
                groupRadio3.Children.Add(rdChoice);

            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

[XAML]

```
        <Grid x:Name="groupRadio"
            ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*"
            IsVisible="{Binding show_radio_type}"
            >                
            <!-- column #1 -->
            <StackLayout x:Name="groupRadio1"
                RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="Radio1"  
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Orientation="Vertical"         
                >
            </StackLayout>
            <!-- column #2 -->
            <StackLayout x:Name="groupRadio2"
                RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="Radio2"  
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Orientation="Vertical"         
                >
            </StackLayout>
            <!-- column #3 -->
            <StackLayout x:Name="groupRadio3"
                RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="Radio3"  
                Grid.Column="2"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Orientation="Vertical"         
                >
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
```

There are 3 groups of RadioButton that are checked for "Packed" in group #1, "Oil" in group #2 and "Inland" in group #3.
I run debug during create process, they are checked correctly but when OnAppearing() finish I got event to uncheck "Packed" and "Oil"

Comment: And how do you want you radio button to work.

Comment: @Prabhat Kumar : thank you for your response, I have editted my Post for your question.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, all the `RadioButton` have the same `GroupName` property.

> `GroupName`, of type string, which defines the name that specifies which
> RadioButton controls are mutually exclusive. This property has a
> default value of null.

That's why even though you have all checked, only the last one looks checked. Because they are mutually exclusive.

You'll just have to add that property when you create the component

```
        RadioButton rdChoice = new RadioButton
        {
            Content = variant.variant_name,                    
            Value= variant.variant_key,
            IsEnabled = true,
            GroupName = variant.groupIdentifierOrSomethingLikethat, 
            IsChecked = variant.default_value,                   
        };

        rdChoice.CheckedChanged += (sender, e) =>
        { 
             ....
        };
        //if (variant.default_value)
        //    rdChoice.IsChecked = true;
```

Comment: thank you for your solution, I have try but problem is still. please kindly see my Post that I have changed as your solution.

Comment: It's weird. Your code looks fine. I edited the answer, try setting the `IsChecked` property when you create the component.

Comment: I have tried but same output sir, the Unchecked event still sent to others. Do it have event that fire after the Page is rendered completely ?

Comment: And what if you call the `GenerateChoice` before the `base.OnAppearing()` ?

Comment: I have try, it's same

Comment: you may load my small test app from link below.

https://onetimesecret.com/secret/rw6f5a5gumswp1v4kyjlkw7r2apskap
pass: so

Comment: Hi @polachetj. I've tried your code and it works fine. I've added 3 options to each column, initial selection being a1, b2 and c3, and they started selected. Tried on uwp and android

Comment: But if your problem is that you don't want to fire `CheckedChanged` at the beggining, then you need to check the radiobutton first, and then add the event

Comment: Thank you very much but problem is still. Now I change UI to take action to set them. This is temporary solution